# How do I get current Unix time in nanoseconds in Android Shell?

Tags: android, shell, unix, time, posix

I need to get timestamps in nanoseconds in Android shell. Using **date** command (from busybox and Cyanogenmod) returns to me this:

```
@A001 # date +%s.%N
1819.N
```

The only other working option that I found is using `www.timeapi.org`.

```
curl -sSw'\n' http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now?\\s.\\N >> ctime_tar.txt
```

However, it requires connection and also takes 0.1 seconds to execute.

What can I use? I really need to get time in nanoseconds, especially something I can execute as a single command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use `EPOCHREALTIME` environment variable:

```
$ adb shell echo \$EPOCHREALTIME
1430637292.923135
```

Comment: This is very helpful. How can you convert it into a format like: HH:MM:SS:NN